# Check element of hasPrevious

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

The main idea of my code is that I want to to do checking after it found "c"

```
A B C D 
    ^
```

then it will check for the previous element inside Arraylist whether it contain "b" or not. if it contain "b" then, it will output "VALID"

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:XX"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                String stringcell = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                al.add(stringcell);
            }

            // row
            ListIterator<String> listIterator = al.listIterator();

            if (al.contains("c")) {
                while (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                    String element = listIterator.previous();
                    if (element.contains("b")) {
                        System.out.println("VALID");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wny not just keep track of the previous value seen:

```
ListIterator<String> listIterator = al.listIterator();
String element;
String prev = "";

while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
    element = listIterator.next();
    if (element.contains("c") && prev.contains("b")) {
        System.out.println("VALID");
        break;
    }
    prev = element;
}
```

Note: This answer assumes that you have a list of strings, in which you want to ask the question of whether any string *contains* the letters `b` and `c`.  If, instead, you want to check if the list contains the entire strings `b` and `c`, then use the answer by @Eran above.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `ListIterator` for that purpose. Instead of `contains`, use `indexOf`. If the index of "c" is positive, check if the element with the previous index is "b".

```
int pos = al.indexOf ("c");
if (pos > 0) {
    if (al.get(pos-1).equals("b")) {
        System.out.println("VALID");
    }
}
```